# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on creating a pivot table in pandas from an excel file. The pivot table was working perfectly fine. but I dont know what happened, now everytime I run the code, I receive this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 0


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c0792069cd70> in <module>
     37 MyPiv = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['weeknum'], 
     38                            values = ['Total Actual Cost','TB ID'],
---> 39                            aggfunc= ('count' , 'mean'))
```

Here is my code for the pivot table

```
df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx", sheet_name = "Mysheet")
MyPiv = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['weeknum'], 
                           values = ['Total Actual Cost','TB ID'],
                           aggfunc= ('count' , 'mean')) 
print(MyPiv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but according to the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) , you could try changing your line to:

```
aggfunc={'Total Actual Cost': np.count, 'TB ID': np.mean})
```

When your code was working, did it use two columns or only one?